# Multiple Virtual networks on a VM in Hyper-V

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, virtualization, hyper-v

I have an Ubuntu VM hosted on a Windows 10 host machine through Hyper-V. For some reasons, I want to make this vm part of multiple networks. I have already created Virtual switches pertaining to the relevant NIC on the host machine.

However the Virtual Machine can be attached to only of them at a time. Is there a way to enable multiple virtual switches in Hyper-V like we could do in Virtual Box?

VirtualBox setting:
[image]

Hyper-V setting:
[image]

Comment: Please post this kind of questions in serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option to Add an hardware , In second pic which you have posted see the first option. Then you add Network in that and do the required settings.